# Parameter Store request timing out inside of AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm attempting to access the AWS SSM Parameter store, like [this article](https://hackernoon.com/you-should-use-ssm-parameter-store-over-lambda-env-variables-5197fc6ea45b) does. I have tested the lambda function locally and it works as expected. When pushed to AWS, however, the lambda fails when attempting to retreive the config; it times out:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "2018-09-02T04:55:49.096Z 71a5006a-ae6c-11e8-9322-313ba5e28048 Task timed out after 6.01 seconds"
}
```

I have the following permissions added to my `serverless.yml`. I have made it as unrestricted as possible to try to find where the error is. Additionally, the parameter is just a string, so it does not use KMS.

```
service: pwaer-messages-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-222f126f
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-756aef12
      - subnet-130f8f3d
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'ssm:**'
      Resource:
        - 'Fn::Join':
          - ':'
          -
            - 'arn:aws:ssm'
            - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
            - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
            - 'parameter/*'

functions:
  receiveText:
    handler: dist/receive.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: sms/parse
          method: post
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I wouldnt connect it to incorrect privileges, since in such case you get right away an IAM error. Which exact function call this is hanging on?

Comment: @LechMigdal that is a great point. It is hanging on `ssm.getParameters`

Comment: Did you try increasing the lambda timeout, just for testing?

Comment: @LechMigdal I had. I've just discovered that removing the VPC resolves this problem, but I need the VPC to access RDS. Shouldn't the `aws-sdk` be able to access aws resources without accessing the public internet?

Comment: Ah, so the lambda cannot access public internet? Try setting up the VPC Endpoint for SSM - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-setting-up-vpc.html

Comment: @LechMigdal if you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Hours of frustration solved a few UI clicks... Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, additionally you may want to edit the title of the question to make it more generic/something that doesn't point to IAM as the root cause of the problem :)

Comment: @LechMigdal good idea.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since mentioned Lambda doesn't have access to the public internet, to access AWS APIs please setup a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html).

As per the description - *"VPC endpoint enables you to privately connect your VPC to supported AWS services and VPC endpoint services"*.

For AWS Systems Manager follow this procedure - [Setting Up VPC Endpoints for Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-setting-up-vpc.html)

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the serverless.yml file?

Comment: @mikespitz_8 you only need to create a single endpoint and all of your lambda functions will use it. You probably shouldn't create it in your serverless file unless you have a single serverless file for all of your lambda functions (which I'd advise against and instead use Terraform to create the endpoint)

Answer (score 4):

This will happen if your Lambda is in a VPC. You need to do two things:

1. Expose the aws ssm service as a VPC Endpoint (see @Lech Migdal's answer)

- the security group for the VPC Endpoint must associate with the security group of the lambda (or service) you wish you allow connectivity

2. Add a self ingress rule for port 443 to the lambda's security group

**CDK Example**

```
const LambdaSecurityGroupIngressRule = new ec2.CfnSecurityGroupIngress(this, "LambdaSecurityGroupIngressRule", {
  groupId: LambdaSecurityGroup.attrGroupId,
  sourceSecurityGroupId: LambdaSecurityGroup.attrGroupId,
  description: "Needed to connect to parameter store from lambda in VPC",
  fromPort: 443,
  ipProtocol: "tcp",
  toPort: 443
})

LambdaSecurityGroupIngressRule.addDependsOn(S3IndexLambdasSecurityGroup)
```

Comment: This answer helped me figure out the issue along with this AWS link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-systems-manager-vpc-endpoints/
I had to add the inbound rule as @cosbor11 suggested